# Issues connecting React hook form validated with zod, with Email Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I am having issues connecting Email js with my React Hook Form, there are various issues like it wont submit on click and can't figure out a way to use `ref` attribute with the `<form>` tag, as it's mentioned in the official documentation.

Here's my code

```
'use client'

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import * as z from "zod";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage } from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

import contact from "@/assets/images/contact.png";


const UserValidation = z.object({
    name: z.string().min(3).max(50),
    email: z.string().email(),
    message: z.string().min(10).max(500),
});

interface Props {
    user: {
        name: string;
        email: string;
        message: string;
    };
}

const Contact = () => {
    const form = useForm({
        resolver: zodResolver(UserValidation),
    });

    const onSubmit = () => (data: z.infer<typeof UserValidation>) => {

        emailjs.sendForm('__service_key', '__template__', JSON.stringify(data), '__API__')
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.text);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error.text);
            });

        form.reset();
    }

    return (


        <div className="my-20">
            <div className="my-12">

                <h1 className="text-3xl md:text-5xl text-center font-serif font-bold">
                    Contact <span className="text-primary">Us</span>
                </h1>

                <h1 className="text-base text-center font-sans font-thin mt-4">
                    We would love to hear from you
                </h1>

            </div>

            <div className="md:grid md:grid-cols-2 mb-12">


                <div className="m-12 md:m-0 md:ml-36 ">



                    <Form {...form} >
                        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                            <FormField control={form.control} name="name" render={({ field }) => (
                                <FormItem className='flex flex-col gap-1 w-full mt-4'>
                                    <FormLabel className='text-light-1 font-sans font-sm'>
                                        Name
                                    </FormLabel >
                                    <FormControl className='flex-1 text-base-semibold text-secondary'>
                                        <Input type='text' className='border-primary account-form_input no focus' {...field} />
                                    </FormControl>
                                </FormItem>)}
                            />
                            <FormField control={form.control} name="email" render={({ field }) => (
                                <FormItem className='flex flex-col gap-1 w-full mt-4'>
                                    <FormLabel className='text-light-1 font-sans font-sm'>
                                        Email
                                    </FormLabel >
                                    <FormControl className='flex-1 text-base-semibold text-secondary'>
                                        <Input type='email' className='border-primary account-form_input no focus' {...field} />
                                    </FormControl>
                                </FormItem>)}
                            />

                            <FormField
                                control={form.control}
                                name="message"
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormItem className='flex flex-col gap-1 mt-4 w-full'>
                                        <FormLabel className='text-light-1 font-sans font-sm'>
                                            Message
                                        </FormLabel>
                                        <FormControl className='flex-1 text-base-semibold text-secondary'>
                                            <Textarea rows={10} className='border-primary account-form_input no focus' {...field} />
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </FormItem>
                                )}
                            />

                            <div className="flex">
                                <Button type="submit" className='bg-primary mt-4 flex-1'>Submit</Button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </Form>
                </div>

                <div className="m-12 md:m-0 md:ml-28">
                    <Image src={contact} alt="contact" className="rounded-lg shadow-custom" height={470} width={470} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Contact;
```

The official documentation mentions it like:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

export const ContactUs = () => {
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', form.current, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="user_name" />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="user_email" />
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

you can also visit my github for the whole code: https://github.com/dipesh2508/health-optima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Your code has some errors

```
// ❌ Here you return a function that returns another function
const onSubmit = () => (data: z.infer<typeof UserValidation>) => {
// ✅ It should be
const onSubmit = (data: z.infer<typeof UserValidation>) => {
```

It looks like emailJs take over getting data from the input fields. It accepts the dom object.

But `form.handleSubmit()` passes the values of the form, not the form object. You'll have to skip the react-hook-form submission and submit it manually.

1. Remove `handleSubmit` from your form:

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
```

2. This function type will be changed

```
const onSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
```

3. Setup the custom function to validate the form

```
const onSubmit = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Validate the form
  const isValid = await form.trigger();

  if (!isValid) {
    // there is some validation errors
    return
  }

  emailjs.sendForm('__service_key', '__template__', event.target, '__API__')
 .then((result) => {
   console.log(result.text);
 }, (error) => {
   console.log(error.text);
 });
 form.reset();
}
```

Another way for doing the same is creating a ref for the form

```
const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null)
// ...

const onSubmit => (data: z.infer<typeof UserValidation>) => {
  emailjs.sendForm('__service_key', '__template__', formRef.current, '__API__')
 .then((result) => {
   console.log(result.text);
 }, (error) => {
   console.log(error.text);
 });
 form.reset();
}
// ...
<form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} ref={formRef}>
```